# Nested DTO's not working with NestJS Swagger

Tags: express, swagger, nestjs

Im trying to use swagger in my new nestjs project.

I use DTO to serialize response but i wanted use it also for swagger and almost everything is ok. Lessons value in swagger is just `"lessons":["string"]` where it should be lesson object with three key:value pairs.

I don't want to use example param to manual define lesson object because i think it might be complicated in larger apps.

`Swagger Example Response`

```
{
  "totalDocs": 0,
  "limit": 0,
  "totalPages": 0,
  "page": 0,
  "pagingCounter": 0,
  "hasPrevPage": true,
  "hasNextPage": true,
  "docs": {
    "title": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "lessons": [
      "string"
    ],
    "price": 0,
    "isFree": false,
    "published": false,
    "slug": "string",
    "createdAt": "2022-11-14T22:33:42.608Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-11-14T22:33:42.608Z"
  }
}
```

`UserCouse.response.dto.ts`

```
class Lesson {
  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Lesson ID' })
  @Expose()
  _id: string;

  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Lesson name' })
  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Lesson type' })
  @Expose()
  type: string;
}

class Course {
  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Course ID' })
  @Expose()
  _id: string;

  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Course title' })
  @Expose()
  title: string;

  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Course description' })
  @Expose()
  description: string;

  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Course slug' })
  @Expose()
  slug: string;

  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Course lessons', type: Lesson, isArray: true })
  @Expose()
  @Type(() => Lesson)
  lessons: Lesson[];

  @Expose()
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'Course lesson count',
    example: 8,
  })
  lessonsCount: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

Dto class name must contain DTO in name. So in my example it’s `LessonDTO`.